# Vaadin components look like text on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, vaadin7

Following by this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oTAK-NGs9ng I have created the same "app" which prints something after user clicks a button. My problem is that components in my app do not look like in tutorial. in my case it looks like simple text .In tutorial it looks like real Vaadin button etc.

Do you have any ideas what did i do wrong ?

You can compare my result vs tutorial results to figure out my problem:
http://www.bargitesty.appspot.com

Comment: app: bargitesty.appspot.com

Comment: are there any missing resources? Check the network tab of the browser and look for 404 on any CSS elements or similar

Comment: Tahnks, I copied: https://github.com/dibacco/vaadin7appengine/tree/master/war/VAADIN/themes/test/styles.css file

I do not know why eclipse did not generate this file for my project.